# How to bridge two WiFi interfaces on raspbian

Tags: wifi, raspbian, bridge

How can I bridge two WiFi interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) on raspbian? I tried using `brctl` but i get the following message `can't add wlan1 to bridge br0 operation not supported`.
Is there any other way to do it?

Let's say that wlan0 is the client that connects to an existing wifi network and that wlan1 is the device that creates a new wifi network. The new wifi network should be a separate network from the one to which is connected wlan0.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish if you get them Bridged?

Comment: You don't call this "bridge"?

Comment: Bridging Shares one computers connection with a computer that has no connection. Pairing is the term you're looking for and that requires 2 Wireless NICS both of the same type or brand, so I ask again: What problem are you trying to solve by pairing/bridging etc?  Also is wlan1 another NIC?

Comment: I already own two wireless NICS of exactly the same type. I'd like to have my own wlan, having access to internet through an existing wifi network, so that all traffic passes through the raspberry PI. I hope I am explaining it properly.

Comment: Are you using a USB Wireless Adapter on the Rasberry Pi?  In order to do what your asking, the Rasberry Pi would need Two Wireless Cards, I to connect to a riuter, and the other would be the ESSID for all the devices connected to it.  You may have better luck connecting the Wired Ethernet to the Router, and using the usb Wireless as the AP.

Comment: I don't have access to a cable. I have two wireless cards which are exactly the same brand and model. I don't know how to create a new wireless network and how to make the new wireless network communicate with the existing wireless network

Comment: Well in that case you don't need paired cards.  Contact your ISP and ask them how to find the name of the Wireless Network that your Router is Broadcasting.  You cannot use the Rasbery Pi as a Firewall because it would have no way to connect to the Router after you set everything up.  To my knowledge, the RaspberriPi can only use USB Wifi.  Are the Cards you have USB, and does your Raspberry have more than one USB.

Comment: I have two USB wifi dongles, both connected to my raspberry pi usb ports.

Comment: Then you need to connect wlan0 to the ESSID that the router broadcasts and then setup wlan1 as an AP for all the devices you want connected.  After doing that add at lleast a DNS Server to your RaspberryPi, and then tell all the devices on your network to use that DNS Server.  Before we go further  do you understand what DNS and Private IP Addresses are?

Comment: Yes I do understand what they are. Will the clients of wlan1 (the AP) be able to access internet? Do I have to do port forwarding? I don't need the clients of wlan1 to be accessed from outside the WLAN.

Comment: Yes on Internet. Maybe on Port Forwarding,  depending on Apps.  You are going to end up Turning your RaspberryPi into a Firewall by using it as a [Secondary Router](http://jacobsalmela.com/raspberry-pi-and-routing-turning-a-pi-into-a-router/).  This is the most configurable method.  It's also the hardest to understand because all the pieces inter-relate.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for asking again: so any client connected to wlan1 will be able to access internet?

Comment: Yes because wlan1 is using wlan0 as its connection

Comment: NP, this setup is the joy of some linux users and the bane of others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't sound like 'bridging' is what you're looking for, it sounds like you want your Pi to act as an access point and share the internet it sees on wlan0 via a new SSID on wlan1.

See this guide for details on how to set that up:
  http://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-raspberry-pi-as-wireless-access-point/